# Computing linear recurring sequences

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a series of numbers A.
There is an index - **k**, which will be passed as an argument to a program.
The series is an arithmetic progression (d=1) until the **k**-th element. For example:

> A<sub>0</sub> = 0, A<sub>1</sub> = 1 [...] A<sub>**k**-1</sub> = **k**-1.

From then on, each element is the sum of the last **k** elements.
For example:

> A<sub>**k**+3</sub> = A<sub>2</sub> + A<sub>3</sub> + [...] + A<sub>**k**+2</sub>.

The user enters a number **n** (and **k**, as mentioned). The program needs to calculate and return the **n**-th element of the described series A.

Example:
**k** = 5, **n** = 8

> A<sub>0</sub> = *0*, A<sub>1</sub> = *1*, A<sub>2</sub> = *2*, A<sub>3</sub> = *3*, A<sub>4</sub> = *4*, A<sub>5</sub> = *10*, A<sub>7</sub> = *20*, A<sub>7</sub> = *39*, A<sub>8</sub> = *76*
>
> A = [0,1,2,3,4,10,20,39,**76**]
>
> A<sub>n</sub> = 76

Any thoughts? This has been bugging me for the last few days, but math was never my thing, so I guess that's the big problem with finding a clever approach (besides having a loop, of course - that doesn't sound clever).
Also, sorry if I made any mistakes, English is not my primary language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding somewhat on Oli Charlesworth's answer, consider the vector

**A**<sub>n</sub> = [ A<sub>n</sub>, A<sub>n-1</sub> ... A<sub>n-k+1</sub> ]

You know that

A<sub>n</sub> = A<sub>n-1</sub> + ... + A<sub>n-k</sub>

so you can express **A**<sub>n</sub> in terms of **A**<sub>n-1</sub> as

**A**<sub>n</sub> = *B* **A**<sub>n-1</sub>

where *B* is the *k* x *k* matrix which has 1s in the top row, 1s below the main diagonal, and zeros everywhere else. For example, for *k*= 4 you have

```
    1   1   1   1
B = 1   0   0   0
    0   1   0   0
    0   0   1   0
```

The solution to the recurrence is now

**A**<sub>n</sub> = *B*<sup>n-k+1</sup> **A**<sub>k-1</sub>

with

**A**<sub>k-1</sub> = [k-1, k-2, k-3 ... 2, 1, 0]

Using a fast matrix exponentiation algorithm, you need to do log(*n* - *k* + 1) matrix multiplications to arrive at the answer, which is approximatly log(*n*) for *n* >> *k*. The cost of a matrix multiplication is *k*<sup>3</sup> so the total complexity is *k*<sup>3</sup> log(*n*)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, well, I am confused at the very beginning... I doubt that if something was wrong with my monitor :D

Comment: @Marcus: Using **bold** to denote a vector is fairly common practice.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can do this without a loop, but you can certainly do better than O(n) time complexity.  If you express this recursion as a matrix operation (similar to [that for the Fibaonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Matrix_form)), then finding the `n`-th term is equivalent to taking the `n`-th power of the matrix, which can be done by [fast exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) in O(log n) time.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in `O(1)` if you find the closed form for the sequence elements. It is a pretty straight forward process for [linear recurring sequences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html) and it involves the use of generating functions. See an [example for the Fibonacci sequence](http://www.math.ufl.edu/~joelar/generatingfibonacci.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The fast matrix exponentiation of @ChrisTaylor and @OliCharlesworth is the way to go.  Finding the closed form mentioned by @AdrianPanasiuk involves finding a diagonalization of the matrix you want to exponentiate.  A sufficiently powerful library may be able to do it for you.

If not, generating functions and linear recurrences boil down to you needing to find all k roots of the polynomial
x<sup>k</sup>-x<sup>k-1</sup>-...-1=0
(including the complex roots).  If you label the roots
r<sub>1</sub>,r<sub>2</sub>,...,r<sub>k</sub>,
then your solution will be of the form
A<sub>n</sub> = Σ<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup> c<sub>i</sub> r<sub>i</sub><sup>n</sup>.
In order to find the values of the c<sub>i</sub>, you'll plug in the known A<sub>n</sub> for 0≤n≤k-1 to get k linear equations with k unknowns.

The only way this could possibly be worth all that trouble would be if you know that k≤4 so that you can go through all of the math for all of the possible k values ahead of time (you won't be able to solve the polynomial equation for larger k).  And if you expect gigantic values for n.  And if you expect a lot of user queries.

Answer (score -1):

If you just write out the first few terms of the series, I think you will see you how to compute this in constant time:

```
 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...
```

So I think it's 2^(n-2) (except for the first term).  Or did I misunderstand?

Oh I just re-read and saw that k can vary -- I gave the answer for k=2?  So k=3 would be:

```
 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 24, ... ?
```

There is definitely a closed form solution; I think maybe

```
 k * 2^(n-k);  n > k
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about that confusion. I now have added an example for k=5/n=8 in the question.

Comment: I don't think this is right; the challenge is to find the sum of the last k elements, not *all* previous elements.